# Publish Provider hosted client web part

Tags: app-part

I have created a provider hosted app that includes an app part (client web part) .

When I press F5 the app installs in debugging mode and I can insert the app part from the ribbon into a page in edit mode.

I have published the app (both the app and the web app) and they appear to have installed successfully. I can click on the app in site contents and the app's default.aspx page opens.

However, when I try to insert the app part into a page it is not available under Insert > App part (or Web Part) in the ribbon.

I cannot find any reference to publishing client web parts on the web (just checking them in debugging mode) so I don't know if I have missed a required step or something else is wrong.

It would be good to hear from someone who has successfully published one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was not removing the app from the app catalogue before updating it.

Once I did this everything worked as expected.